# why does my smo run so slowly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I implemented a smo algorithm in python. As I just do it as a practice so I didn't use some scientific computing library such as numpy and scipy . I just want it work correct。 But when I test my code on [diabetes](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Diabetes), it keeps running for a week! I have checked my code many times and I also found some errors. but after I correct these errors, the code still runs too slow. I don't know if there are some errors that I didn't checked out or the smo is just inherently so slow.

So is there some common errors that could make code runs slow? I wrote my program referring to the pseudo-code of the [smo paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69644/tr-98-14.pdf)
Thanks very much.

Below is my code.

```
#encoding=utf8
import math
import random

class SVM(object):
    def __init__(self, dataset, target, C=0.001, tolerance=0.001):
        self.dataset=dataset
        self.target=target
        self.C=C
        self.tolerance=tolerance
        self.alpha=[0.0 for i in range(len(dataset))]
        self.E={}
        self.b=0.0
        self.w=[0.0 for i in range(len(dataset[0]))]

    def train(self):
        numChanged=0
        exampleAll=1

        trainset_size=len(self.dataset)
        iter=0
        while numChanged > 0 or exampleAll:
            numChanged=0
            if exampleAll: 
                for i in range(trainset_size):
                    numChanged+=self.examineExample(i)
                iter+=1
            else:
                for i in range(trainset_size):
                    if self.alpha[i] > 0 and self.alpha[i] < self.C: 
                        numChanged+=self.examineExample(i)
                iter+=1
            if exampleAll:
                exampleAll=0
            elif numChanged == 0:
                exampleAll=1
            print "iter", iter
            print "alpha", "\t".join([str(i) for i in self.alpha])
            print "target", "\t".join(self.target)
        for j in range(len(self.trainset[0])):
            for i in range(trainset_size):
                self.w[j] +=self.alpha[i]*int(self.target[i])*float(self.dataset[i][j])

    def examineExample(self, i2):
        print "in examineExample", i2
        print "alpha", "\t".join([str(i) for i in self.alpha])
        alpha2=self.alpha[i2]
        y2=int(self.target[i2])
        e2=self.calculateE(i2)
        r2=e2*y2
        print "r2", r2

        if r2 < -self.tolerance and self.alpha[i2] < self.C or r2 > self.tolerance and self.alpha[i2] > 0: #i2违反了kkt条件
            i1=self.select_i1(i2,e2)
            if self.takeStep(i1, i2):
                return 1
            else: 
                all_sample_index=[i for i in range(len(self.dataset)) ]
                random.shuffle(all_sample_index)
                for k in range(len(all_sample_index)):
                    i1=all_sample_index[k]
                    if self.alpha[i1] > 0 and self.alpha[i1] < self.C:
                        if self.takeStep(i1, i2):
                            return 1

                random.shuffle(all_sample_index)
                for k in range(len(all_sample_index)):
                    i1=all_sample_index[k]
                    if self.takeStep(i1,i2):
                        return 1
        return 0

    def takeStep(self, i1, i2):
        print "in takeStep", i1, i2
        if i1==i2:
            return 0
        alpha1=self.alpha[i1]
        y1=int(self.target[i1])
        e1=self.calculateE(i1)

        alpha2=self.alpha[i2]
        y2=int(self.target[i2])
        e2=self.calculateE(i2)

        s=y1*y2

        if y1 != y2:
            L=max(0, alpha2-alpha1)
            H=min(self.C, self.C+alpha2-alpha1)
        if y1== y2:
            L=max(0, alpha2+alpha1-self.C)
            H=min(self.C, alpha2+alpha1)
        if L==H:
            return 0
        k11=self.kernel(i1, i1)
        k12=self.kernel(i1, i2)
        k22=self.kernel(i2, i2)
        eta=k11+k22-2*k12

        if eta > 0:
            self.alpha[i2]=alpha2+y2*(e1-e2)/eta
            if self.alpha[i2] < L:
                self.alpha[i2]=L
            if self.alpha[i2] >H:
                self.alpha[i2]=H

            print "abs", abs(self.alpha[i2] - alpha2)
            if abs(self.alpha[i2] - alpha2) < 0.00001
                return 0

            self.alpha[i1]=alpha1+s*(alpha2-self.alpha[i2])

            b1=self.b-e1-y1*(self.alpha[i1]-alpha1)*self.kernel(i1,i1)-y2*(self.alpha[i2]-alpha2)*self.kernel(i1,i2)
            b2=self.b-e2-y1*(self.alpha[i1]-alpha1)*self.kernel(i1,i2)-y2*(self.alpha[i2]-alpha2)*self.kernel(i2,i2)

            print "two old alpha", alpha1, alpha2
            print "two alpha", self.alpha[i1] ,self.alpha[i2] 
            if self.alpha[i1] >0 and self.alpha[i1] < self.C and self.alpha[i2] > 0 and self.alpha[i2] < self.C:
                print "two b",  b1, b2
            if self.alpha[i1] >0 and self.alpha[i1] < self.C:
                self.b=b1
            elif self.alpha[i2] > 0 and self.alpha[i2] < self.C:
                self.b=b2
            else:
                self.b=(b1+b2)/2
            self.E[i2]=self.calculateE(i2) 
            self.E[i1]=self.calculateE(i1)
            return 1  
        else:
            return 0

    def select_i1(self, i, Ei ):
        maxK=-1;
        maxDeltaE=0.0
        Ej=0

        self.E[i]=Ei

        for k in range(len(self.dataset)):
            if self.alpha[k]  > 0 and self.alpha[k] < self.C:
                Ek=self.calculateE(k)
                deltaE=Ek-Ei
                if abs(deltaE) > maxDeltaE:
                    maxK=k
                    maxDeltaE=deltaE
                    Ej=Ek

        if maxK != -1:
            return maxK
        else:
            j=i
            while j == i:
                j=random.randint(0, len(self.dataset))
            return j

    def calculateE(self, i):
        f_x=0.0
        trainset_size=len(self.dataset)
        for k in range(trainset_size):
            f_x+=(self.alpha[k]*int(self.target[k])*self.kernel(k,i))
        f_x+=self.b
        e_x=f_x-float(self.target[i])
        return e_x


    def kernel(self, i, j): 
        return sum([float(self.dataset[i][k])*float(self.dataset[j][k]) for k in range(len(self.dataset[i]))])

    def test(self, testset, testset_target):
        precision=0.0
        correct=0
        for k in range(len(testset)):
            sample =testset[k]
            pred_value=0.0
            for i in range(len(sample)):
                pred_value+=self.w[i]*sample[i]
                pred_value+=self.b

            if pred_value >= 0:
                label=1
            else:
                label=-1
            if testset_target[k] == label:
                correct+=1

        precision=correct/(float(len(testset_target)))

        return precision

def read_libsvm_format_file(dataset_filename):
        dataset_file=file(dataset_filename,'r')
        dataset_label=[]
        dataset=[]
        for line in dataset_file:
            splitted=line.strip().split()
            dataset_label.append(splitted[0])
            sample=[]
            for i in range(1,len(splitted)):
                index_value=splitted[i].split(":")
                sample.append(index_value[1])
            dataset.append(sample)
        return dataset, dataset_label

if __name__ == "__main__":
        dataset, target =read_libsvm_format_file('diabetes')

        trainset_size=500
        index=range(len(dataset))
        random.shuffle(index) 
        trainset=[ dataset[index[i]] for i in range(trainset_size) ]
        trainset_target=[ target[index[i]] for i in range(trainset_size) ]

        testset=[ dataset[index[i]] for i in range(trainset_size, len(index)) ]
        testset_target=[ target[index[i]] for i in range(trainset_size, len(index)) ]

        svm=SVM(dataset, target)
        svm.train()
```

Comment: Try using the `cProfile` library to look for bottlenecks in you code.

Answer (score 3):

## General problems

Unfortunately, the most common error in scientific python programming that causes code to run slow is... to use pure python. Python loops are slow, period. [And by slow I mean extremely slow.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26323/how-slow-is-python-really-or-how-fast-is-your-language) Even assuming that eveything is perfectly correct, you will end up with extremely slow optimizer unless you do one of the following:

- switch to [Cython](http://cython.org/) (gives you access to the beauty of typed loops)
- use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) (basic numeric library)
- try to run code through [pypy](http://pypy.org/) (it is not a library, it is different interpreter, faster one)

## Bugs

1. There is no `:` after

   ```
   if abs(self.alpha[i2] - alpha2) < 0.00001
   ```

   So it will not even run.
2. Next, after fixing it and runing on `diabetes` it crashes

   ```
   r2 -0.999256460902
   in takeStep 658 2
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "a.py", line 218, in <module>
           svm.train()
         File "a.py", line 26, in train
           numChanged+=self.examineExample(i)
         File "a.py", line 55, in examineExample
           if self.takeStep(i1, i2):
         File "a.py", line 79, in takeStep
           e1=self.calculateE(i1)
         File "a.py", line 160, in calculateE
           f_x+=(self.alpha[k]*int(self.target[k])*self.kernel(k,i))
         File "a.py", line 167, in kernel
           return sum([float(self.dataset[i][k])*float(self.dataset[j][k]) for k in range(len(self.dataset[i]))])
       IndexError: list index out of range
   ```

   which is caused by your **invalid reading function**. libsvm (svmlight) dataformat is **sparse**, so some of the dimensions might be missing - your code assumes that it does not.
3. You even read your data as **strings**

   ```
   index_value=splitted[i].split(":")
   sample.append(index_value[1])
   ```

   It should be (after you preallocate your sample lists so they are big enough to fit data, or use defaultdicts `sample = defaultdict(lambda: 0)`).

   ```
   index_value=splitted[i].split(":")
   sample[int(index_value[0])-1] = float(index_value[1])
   ```

   The same applies to reading labels. Consequently you have dozens of completely redundant type conversions in your code (all your current `float()` and `int()` calls are redundant).
4. There is also error, in final building of `w`:

   ```
   [...] self.trainset [...] // you do not have a "trainset" field in SVM
   ```
5. In testing code you add intercept (`b`) multiple times

   ```
   for i in range(len(sample)):
           pred_value+=self.w[i] * sample[i]
           pred_value+=self.b
   ```

   while it should be

   ```
   for i in range(len(sample)):
           pred_value+=self.w[i] * sample[i]
   pred_value+=self.b
   ```
6. I would not be suprised if one would find also many errors in SMO itself, which might cause the algorithm to not converge at all, but for now I only managed to find the above.

## After fixes

after fixing all of the above, removing all debug printing messages and running with `pypy` I get following model:

> [-0.7725132490683443, -2.8232379861128907, 0.5166865781499452,
>   0.1494369704938019, 0.1533317981122747, -1.9500615428909012, -0.7957828887451327, -0.12523832631571777]

while scikit-learn gives

> [ 0.77296251  2.82387247 -0.51692311 -0.14987696 -0.15312237 
>   1.94999242
>      0.79593224  0.12527931]

So up to sign it is the same model.

When using `C=1` both codes end up with training set accuracy `0.776041666667`

## Time comparison

- using your code [with type casting] and pure python

> real  9m11.017s

- using your code [with type casting] and `pypy`

> real  0m47.033s

- using your code [without type casting] and `pypy`

> real  0m40.215s

- using scikit-learn SMO (C code)

> real  0m0.338s

## Final remarks

It appears that most of your errors are located in data reading utilities. Furthermore, as stated at the begining - "classic" python interpreter has extremely slow loops, so you either have to use `pypy` (and lack of support for many libraries), or `cython` (and more complex development) or at least numerical libraries such as `numpy` and `scipy`.

Comment: Thanks very much for checking my program.As I uploaded a wrong version of my program,  some obvious errors that cause it fail to run doesn't exist in my  final version. But bug #3 is really my fault. I didn't convert string to float when I read the data file. As to error #2, I have to apologize to you as I paste another url of the Diabetes dataset while actually I use [this  in libsvmtools](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/diabetes) in my test

Comment: when I correct the above errors in my program that mentioned above and use pypy to run my python program, the program still runs for a long time.But when I use sklearn to test, the program gives result in less than 1 second. I think the smo algorithms itself has some erros and I will check it. Thanks.